# Update some settings of an existing resource using Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-devops

I'm new to Cloud Formation. I want to update the settings of already created a lot of RDS instances using Cloud Formation. I don't have the info about either those resources were created through CF or manually. Is it possible to update such resources with CF?
I can think of another way like I can use AWS SDK (boto3) but doing it with CF is perefrable.

Comment: Only through custom resources.

Comment: Can you explain? How we can do this using custom resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this from CloudFormation (CF) is to develop your own CF [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). This will be a lambda function which will use AWS SDK to query the state of your RDS databases, and perform any actions you want.

Since its **fully custom**, you can program any logic which satisfies your requirements.

If the resources were created manually, you can also [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) them to CF, and then update using CF.

Comment: okay, so there isn't a way that. I define only that configuration in the RDS CF template which I want to update and pass DB identified to CF?

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb This is the only way if you don't know if "those resources were created through CF or manually".

Comment: what if those were created through CF then what will be the possible solution?

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb Then just edit your CF template and update your stack. Nothing special about that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73134809/cloud-formation-for-cloud-watch-alarms-on-metrics-generated-by-cw-agent

Comment: If you have some time can you please go through the above question. Thanks