# Cloud Formation for Cloud Watch Alarms on metrics generated by CW Agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, cloudwatch-alarms

I have installed CW Agent on multiple EC2 instances to fetch the storage used. I'm getting disk_used_percent metrics from multiple instances like this,

[image]

Since the name of the metric is same for all the instances, If I create a CW alarm from the console I will click on metric and will create an alarm but I'm trying to do it from Cloud Formation script. In CF script there is only an option for Namespace which will be CWAgent in my case and metric name which will be disk_used_percent. My question is how can I define which instance metric I want to fetch,
Here are the screenshots for manually created alarm and CF created alarm,

[image: Manually Created]

[image: CF Created]

How to define instance_id and other parameters in CF script? I can't find any of these option on CW CF sample scripts on AWS website.

```
  CloudWatchAlarm:
  Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
  Properties:
    AlarmName: "disk-space-threshold"
    AlarmDescription: "A Cloudwatch Alarm that triggers when disk space of EBS is less than 50%"
    MetricName: "disk_used_percent"
    Namespace: "CWAgent"
    Statistic: "Average"
    Period: "60"
    EvaluationPeriods: "1"
    Threshold: "1"
    ComparisonOperator: "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
    TreatMissingData: "notBreaching"
```

Comment: Instance id is set through cw agent config files. How did you configure the agent?

Comment: I didn't set the instance_id. While creating config file through wizard, it asked that do you want information of instance_id, ami_id and it marked that yes.

Comment: my issue is when I want to create alarms using CF for metric (disk_used_percent) but in the screenshot, you can see that there are multiple metrics with the same name. So when you check 2nd screenshot (Manually Created Alarm), you can see that instance_id etc is mentioned. How can I define those instance_id through CF script.

Comment: You can see my CF script, there is only option of namespace and metric name, how I will define other settings which you can see in 2nd screenshot like instance_id, path, device etc

Comment: You have to add Dimensions, as I wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to define instance_id and other parameters in CF script?

You need to add [Dimensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html#cfn-cloudwatch-alarms-dimension) to your `AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm`. `InstanceId` is one of the dimensions of your `disk_used_percent` metric.

Comment: I have set the dimensions using CF and still, I'm not getting any data on my alarm dashboard. Status is insufficient data.

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb Just have to wait. Otherwise this could be a new issue, thus new question can be asked.

Comment: can we filter on basis of few dimensions?

Comment: like in 1st screenshot, I want to get the metric on basis of Instance ID and Device

Comment: can you please look into this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73145312/query-cloud-watch-metrics-on-basis-of-dimensions-using-cloud-formation
Thanks