# Query Cloud Watch Metrics on basis of Dimensions using Cloud Formation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have installed CW agent on my EC2 Linux Machine and received disk_used_percemt metric of each partition. I want to create CW Alarm on only one partition. I'm getting the following dimensions for each metric,
Instance name, InstanceId, ImageId, device, fstype, path, Metric name

[image]

Now I want to create an alarm using CW where,

**Namespace: CWAgent**

**Metric name: disk_used_percent**

**InstanceId: X**

**device: xvda1**

I'm using the following CF code,

```
  CloudWatchAlarm:
  Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
  Properties:
    AlarmName: "disk-space-threshold"
    AlarmDescription: "A Cloudwatch Alarm that triggers when disk space of EBS is less than 50%"
    MetricName: "disk_used_percent"
    Namespace: "CWAgent"
    Statistic: "Average"
    Period: "60"
    EvaluationPeriods: "1"
    Threshold: "75"
    ComparisonOperator: "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
    TreatMissingData: "missing"
    Dimensions:
     - Name: InstanceId
       Value: !Ref InstanceID
     - Name: ImageId
       Value: !Ref ImageID
     - Name: device
       Value: !Ref Device
```

When an alarm is created, it is showing insufficient data. What can be the possible issue?

Comment: Do you actually have data in the metric?

Comment: Yes I do have data in that matric, If I give complete dimensions then it shows data.

Comment: What do you mean by "complete dimensions"?

Comment: Complete dimensions mean, in screenshot there are multiple dimensions and If I add all those dimensions in CF template then metric shows data but I want to filter on 3 dimensions above

Answer (score 0):

You can't filter by 3 dimensions. You always have to use full set of dimensions to identify a metric.

Comment: Is there any other I can filter on instance_id?

Comment: @AbdulHaseeb You could look maybe on [Metric Math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) to aggregate different metrics into one.